# In PHP - how do you extend a session?

Tags: php

All,

Sorry - this is a very simple question that has surely been answered a 1,000 times, but I can't find a clear, precise explanation.

When you create a session, that session will last a pre-determined amount of time before it expires (e.g., 30 minutes).

However - if the user continues to interact with your site - you wouldn't want the session to expire 30 minutes after the session is first created. Instead, you'd want to to expire 30 minutes after ***the last user interaction.***

So - my question - what ***exactly*** extends a session? (That is, "resets" the 30-minute clock?)

(By "using", I mean navigating from one page too another, or triggering AJAX requests).

E.g., if every 5 minutes, you call a script that executes `session_start()`?

Or, if you modify a session variable? E.g., `$_SESSION['last_touched'] = time();`

Or, if the user simply calls for a resource on the server? (E.g., loads "transparent.gif")

Long story short - I want to make sure the session doesn't expire ***while*** the user is actually using the site, so I would like to know exactly what actions/functions extend the session's lifespan.

Note that I'm ***not*** asking any of these questions:

1. How do I set the timeout period for LONG period of time, or change the default timeout?
2. How do keep the session from expiring when the user IS NOT interacting with the site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any call to `session_start()`; unless you have session.autostart set in your php.ini; in which case it's any request to a php script on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `session_start()` successfully will reset the session lifetime.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Just to confirm... Simply calling `session_start()` resets the lifetime, even if I don't modify any of the `$_SESSION` properties? And, are there any other actions that accomplish this? In other words, if a script DOESN'T call `session_start()`, it ***won't*** extend the session's lifespan?

Comment: @mattstuehler: Yes, unless you have enabled `session.autostart` as Mark very correctly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Every call to session_start() creates or extends the session.

And how long will it be keep after the last call is determined by the  [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) variable

Answer (score 1):

The session timeout is defined in a php environment variable (look for session.gc_maxlifetime).

Comment: That's not what `session.gc_maxlifetime` does.